# Remove a vertex from a connected graph to obtain a connected subgraph

Tags: algorithm, math, graph-theory

I have the impression that if I take a simple, connected graph then I can (provided it has a vertex number greater than or equal to 2) remove a vertex and obtain a connected subgraph.

This doesn't work with all vertices, there are some that I can't remove.
For instance,
[image]

I can't remove E without losing connectivity but I can remove A,B,C or D.

But there is always one that I can rule out. Do you have a way to prove this result?

Comment: can you explain further on what you mean by - "This doesn't work with all vertices, there are some that I can't remove"

Comment: @subasri_ Of course, I just did!

Comment: This doesn't look like a question about one of [these topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Having said that, [see here](https://gustavus.edu/academics/departments/mathematics-computer-science-and-statistics/max/courses/F2011/MCS-236/MaximumCutVertices.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let G be any connected graph. Then G has at least one spanning tree. Let T be any spanning tree of G. Let v be any leaf of T. If we delete v, T \ {v} is connected, and is a subgraph of G \ {v} so G \ {v} is connected.

Well-known results this uses:

- Every connected graph has at least 1 spanning tree
- Deleting a leaf from an n-vertex tree results in an (n-1)-vertex tree

Answer (score 1):

The concept you are referring to can be related to the concept of `Articulation Point`, also called as `Cut Vertex`.

If there exists a vertex `v` in a connected component, which when removed breaks the graph would become disconnected i.e. break into two or more components

There are certain conditions that would qualify a node for an articulation point. So if the graph is identified to have no such vertices, then graph remains as a single connected component even when any vertex is removed

Refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component) for more information